# Formula needed for summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am not quite sure that the title is correct for the following scenario:

I have to pay a yearly maintenance fee A, but this fee increases by 5% each year (this is a fixed rate), so on my second year I pay A + 0.05xA or A(1+0.05) or Ax1.05. In year n, I would have to pay A multiplied by 1.05 to the power of (n-1).

So:

In Year 1 I pay A, In Year 2 I pay A x 1.05, In Year 3 I pay A x 1.05 to the power of 2, ... , In Year n I pay A x 1.05 to the power of (n-1).

I am not quite sure that the above formulas are correct, I did my best, but I'm not a mathematician.

I would need a formula that would add up the maintenance fees accumulated over the years, that is how much I paid in total over n years, considering the yearly increase of 5%. That is Year 1 + Year 2 + Year 3 + ... + Year n

Please help. Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: So far right. The series $A+Ar+Ar^2+\cdots +Ar^{n-1}$ is a finite geometric series. The sum (if $r\ne 1$) is $\frac{A(r^n-1)}{r-1}$. Here $r=1.05$. The formula I quoted may be a standard fact that you are expected to know. The derivation is not difficult.

Comment: You are welcome. It turned out that others answered, so the comment was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

To give a short answer, the total payment is (with $q=1.05$)
$$ A\cdot \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}=20A(q^n-1).$$
The formula is well-known for *compound interest* as this.

Comment: Thank you so much! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For year $n$ you are trying to find 
$$\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} (1+q)^m$$ where $q$ is the interest rate which is $0.05$.
(Check it out, for years 1, 2, and 3, to be convinced this is right.)

This is just a geometric series, with starting value $1$ and ratio $(1+q)$, so the sum up to $m=n-1$  is
$$
\frac{1-(1+q)^{n}}{1-(1+q)} = \frac{(1+q)^{n}-1}{q}
$$
or with $q = \frac{1}{20}$
$$
20 \cdot \left( 1.05^n -1 \right) $$

Comment: Thank you so much! Greatly appreciated!